# Docker failed to compute cache key

Tags: package-management, 22.04, java, docker, jdk

I try to run docker in my spring boot, and when i add Dockerfile at the directory booting-web/ and put some code like this :

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-17-slim as BUILDER 
ARG VERSION=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
WORKDIR /build/
COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/

RUN mvn clean package 
COPY target/booting-web-${VERSION}.jar target/application.jar


FROM openjdk:17-oracle
WORKDIR /app/

COPY --from=BUILDER /build/target/application.jar /app/

CMD java -jar /app/application.jar
```

After that i save the docker file, and then open the terminal, i type `sudo docker build -t booting-web .` and i got an error saying like this :

```
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 386B                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17-oracle                                                           1.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.6.3-openjdk-17-slim                                                 0.9s
 => CANCELED [builder 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.6.3-openjdk-17-slim@sha256:6d8d6569d5a3b81e033e2f9905290fbd9c9b509f  0.3s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/maven:3.6.3-openjdk-17-slim@sha256:6d8d6569d5a3b81e033e2f9905290fbd9c9b509fce1889cdea5692b00  0.1s
 => => sha256:6d8d6569d5a3b81e033e2f9905290fbd9c9b509fce1889cdea5692b003edc9bb 549B / 549B                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 868B                                                                                              0.0s
 => CANCELED [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:17-oracle@sha256:83ffa182a7cfc8313583fe1cc42172a48a021f368a1ff11fe0  0.4s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/openjdk:17-oracle@sha256:83ffa182a7cfc8313583fe1cc42172a48a021f368a1ff11fe0d957c3b3b8a620     0.1s
 => => sha256:83ffa182a7cfc8313583fe1cc42172a48a021f368a1ff11fe0d957c3b3b8a620 547B / 547B                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:98f0304b3a3b7c12ce641177a99d1f3be56f532473a528fda38d53d519cafb13 954B / 954B                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:5e28ba2b4cdb3a7c3bd0ee2e635a5f6481682b77eabf8b51a17ea8bfe1c05697 4.45kB / 4.45kB                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 2/6] WORKDIR /build/                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 3/6] COPY pom.xml /build/                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 4/6] COPY src /build/src/                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 5/6] RUN mvn clean package                                                                                 0.0s
 => ERROR [builder 6/6] COPY target/Booting-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar target/application.jar                                      0.0s
------
 > [builder 6/6] COPY target/Booting-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar target/application.jar:
------
Dockerfile:8
--------------------
   6 |     
   7 |     RUN mvn clean package 
   8 | >>> COPY target/Booting-web-${VERSION}.jar target/application.jar
   9 |     
  10 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 269de514-ac0b-4686-9da1-3bee7003c2b0::hwlt7penrckamosf5gw598w51: "/target/Booting-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar": not found
```

i've been try to change the jdk version from this :

```
FROM openjdk:17.0.8.1-jre-slim
WORKDIR /app/
```

Into this :

```
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
WORKDIR /app/
```

But it won't work. Any idea?